Flask Static File Serving Issue: 404 Error for Video File
I'm encountering an issue with static files in my Flask application and would appreciate some guidance on resolving it as I have almost no experience in web development.
I apologize if I'm not explaining things well, but here's a summary of the problem:
Problem:
When attempting to load static files (mp4 video) on my Flask website, I'm consistently receiving a 404 error. Despite ensuring correct file paths and permissions, I'm unable to resolve the issue, I realize there are a lot of questions already about serving static files but the solutions presentes are not working and the situations are a bit different as I only want to add a background video to my website.
Here's the relevant code snippets from my Flask application:
Flask application setup
app = Flask(__name__)
app._static_folder = '/static'


HTML/CSS for background video
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Barcode Wall Control Server</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style>
        @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
            .sidebar {padding-top: 15px;}
            .sidebar a {font-size: 18px;}
        }

        #mainContent {
        padding: 20px;
        }

        /*Video Background */
        #backVideo {
            position: fixed;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            min-width: 100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            width: auto;
            height: auto;
            z-index: -1;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #b8b7b74f;">

    <video autoplay loop muted id="backVideo">
        <source src="{{url_for('static', filename='barcode.mp4')}}" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
</body>  

My terminal shows the following error message when attempting to load the static files:
[15/May/2024 14:38:46] "GET /static/barcode.mp4 HTTP/1.1" 404
PS. When I run the html code directly without the server the video loads without a problem.

There's no property under flask app called _static_folder. It's static_folder and it takes an absolute path to the static folder. The default value is static and it points to the static folder under your app. Are you trying to point your static folder specifically to the root /static folder?

Thank you for the reply. I corrected the syntax problem like you explained, however I'm not sure how to answer your question because like I said I don't have any experience with this and I added that code as an attempt to solve my issue based on other people's posts of similar problems. After correcting the code to static_folder my problem remains sadly.

I think you have a few issues here. You haven't specified which version of Flask you're using, but I don't recall ever seeing an option to specify the static path using _static_folder (i.e. with an underscore prefix).
You should be able to configure it using the Flask instance's static_folder property or by providing a static_folder=... kwarg to the Flask constructor.
The other issue is that the path should be relative or an absolute path (e.g. /static on your file system), which I'm assuming you don't want -- although it does work. From the docs, "Relative to the application root_path or an absolute path."
So, you should probably change your code to something like:
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="static") 
# or 
# app.static_folder = "static"

It's also worth noting that, static is the default. So, if that's not working, you may want to ensure that the static folder is positioned correctly according to the application's root_path. For example,
├── app
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── routes.py
│   └── *static*

Try adding the following after you instantiate your Flask instance to determine why static assets aren't being served:
print(app.root_path)
print(app.has_static_folder)
print(app.static_folder)
import os
names = os.listdir(os.path.join(app.static_folder))
print(names) # list of static files


Thanks for the reply.
The versions I am using are Python 3.11.2, Flask 3.0.3, Werkzeug 3.0.3
I corrected like you suggested but still have the same problem
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder="static")
My server structure is the following:
├── app │   ├── __init__.py │   ├── routes.py │   └── static │       ├── barcode.mp4 │       └── space.png └── templates     └── index.html

@Gundi Hm. I've added some suggestions which might help you determine why you're not able to access those assets.
